# Is there a way to make a human character that is kept alive by an unfinished task?

Tags: character-creation, world-of-darkness, character-death

Is there a way to design a human character in World of Darkness who is unable to die permanently until he does (or finds out) something? Examples of this sort of story include [The Deaths of Ian Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deaths_of_Ian_Stone), [Run Lola Run](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_Lola_Run), or [Kenny from South Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenny_McCormick).

We are playing in the Old World of Darkness — I'm new to it, but we're using Vampire: The Masquerade, Werewolf: The Apocalypse, and Mage: The Ascension. I think homebrew material is also accepted since there is a highlander character too.

Comment: I take it something like the Risen (http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Risen), a dead human who comes back to life to complete a quest, isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: That is a one time thing - not over and over again - and takes a wraith quite a bit of effort to do.

Answer (score 5):

In the original World of Darkness: Sorcerer splatbook, there is a 5-7 point Merit: Immortal. The 7 point version essentially makes the character unkillable. No matter how severe the damage, they will eventually regenerate it. However, there is a single situation/circumstance/or event that can kill the character, which is agreed upon by the player and the ST.

If that Merit were allowed, I would say that yes, there is a way to create a character who only dies when they discover some piece of information or perform some specific action. I'd be hesitant to allow it in my own game if the action or knowledge wasn't something integral to the character's motivations/concept. An immortal archaeologist obsessed with secret of Enoch, and whose death revolves around its discovery could make for an interesting character (especially if their death was triggered by crossing the Shroud into the Enoch in the Shadowlands). Assuming of course, that all of that is even relevant in the particular chronicle said character will be playing in.

An immortal who is going to die by eating an alien from Beta Centauri is both less interesting, willfully out of tone with the World of Darkness, and completely bonkers. So, probably not going to get approved.

Answer (score 4):

## No.

There is nothing to support this in the published universe of either World of Darkness.  There are only things that come close, *Mummy: the Resurrection* being the closest.  As you have indicated that your storyteller has allowed homebrew races, and have also indicated that you wish for your character to actually be able to die only to return to life, I can offer some suggestions.  These have no mechanical component, since they are just changing the fluf around already existing concepts.

### Faster Mummies

If you change the fluf of Mummy - come up with your own origin story for how you became immortal, and made reincarnation faster to fit the story, the game supports immortal characters.  This option has many drawbacks, as it also includes a great deal of magical powers for the character.

### Be another Highlander

You already have Highlander at the table, and using the same rules for your immortal and theirs would be a trivial switch.  As Highlanders do not have many magical powers (sensing another immortal being the only one of note), simply changing the death condition will suffice.  I should note, though, that there are literally hundreds of rules sets for playing Highlander style immortals, so your mileage may very.

To reiterate, ***No, there is no rules published for what you want to do.***  My actionable advice is to ***change the fluf of an already tested and already in use home brew supplement.***

Answer (score 2):

As Tritium mentioned corewise its a no for a human character BUT there are ways to work around it. That is if it is NOT the human that should have the power:

- There are beings in the owod who can bring back dead humans with ease regardless of the circumstances of death. I THINK mages have the power to do that (not much into mage myself though but with how powerful they were in owod I'm pretty sure they also could do that) and demons also have the power. A demon or even an earthbound (completely monstrous demon who is bound to places or objects) could easily bring back the human again and again if they think that what he shall do or find out is important enough for them to use up so many resources and could easily also result in quite a few story hooks (if you know the film trilogy gods army there are some examples there where humans did not want to be brought back but did because they were needed for some task).

A second possibility would be if the character only THINKS he is human while not being so. An example here is demon the fallen where the demon who merges with a host can loose all of his memories in the process. Only downside is when the host dies the demon must merge with a new host and take over that ones body. Thus it could be the same "human" but a different face (and different base stats according to core rules).

Another alternative there would be if you want to go down a bit of a houserulish path and introduce something like "Geist" from nwod into owod. In geist a dead one made a deal with a spirit/ghost hybrid called a Geist and fuses with it being brought back to live. And will be brought back again if dead (although at the loss of power). If you like that approach you could use demon the fallen there and say that the human overrid the will of the demon possessing him and fused with it. And every time he inhabits a new host the host gets transformed into the original human over the course of a night. Another possibility would be to say there that your character is sort of a Nephilim brought by a demon who has manifested in a human and a human and use a similar rule as above. Thus instead of gaining control of a new host and gaining that ones stats, the new host gets transformed into the "original" human that the character was.

Answer (score 0):

as Tritium21 mentioned, the only truly immortal characters in oWoD are mummies - but then please don't treat it as a "god mode" character with unlimited lives - mummies do come back but it often takes years.
If you are more interested by immortality of spirit then you have few more options: one is the mage's avatar (well, almost immortality: avatar can be permanently destroyed i.e. by turning mage into a vampire) - after the mage dies it will attach itself to a new awakened soul and (in some cases) bring back lots of personality from the original character. If you'd like to follow this path, there is actually system that converts really nice to oWoD setting called "[Nephilim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephilim_(role-playing_game))", where players are elemental-like being possessing mortal's body, and after host dies they are forced to look for new one or fall asleep bound to an item.

Another options: Technocracy can easily produce lots of clones for same character - think "Agent Smith" from the "Matrix"- please note that such characters won't be a fully awakened mage, but producing very powerful, smart and strong mortals/cyborgs equipped with latest technology is well within their abilities.

Comment: Not sure if the avatar is indestructible if I remember correctly it is destroyed when a mage is turned into a vampire or am I wrong there?

Comment: Yes, you are right, otherwise we would have vampire with mage's powers. Same happens when mage becomes a mummy, also avatar is lost when nephandi dies (but there was a story about Euthanatos mage who died to purify her corrupted avatar, so I'm not 100% sure about this)

Comment: owod was sadly a bit contradictionary at some times

Comment: Yes, when it came to cosmology or questions like "who rules the world", which in my opinion was better and more realistic than giving straight answer - after all when you ask such question in real life to people from different cultures/backgrounds you will get different answers. Back to your question about embrace destroying avatar - you were right, I simply forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, I assume this character has always managed to escape death (due to a lucky die scoring 10, or any sort of divine intervention) instead of dying-resurrecting over and over.

First of all, of course you can make a human character! Mages can create/alter reality, but biologically they are simple humans, as opposed to vamps or lycans. The problem with this human is that it will be a "dormant", i.e., ignorant of all things magic(k).

In Mage: The Ascension 2nd. Ed. Revised, there is a trait that can be "traited" (hehe) either as a merit or a flaw: Geasa.

I'll be honest and say I haven't opened my book for years now. But as far as I remember, a character having a geas is exactly what you described: an unfinished task that must be done over and over and over until satisfactory to the char's background.

Be aware that this is a 1- to 5-point trait, so depending on the magnitude of the geas, the more points should be assigned.